# Autorelease for beginners

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I found this very useful definition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165619/to-autorelease-or-not-to-autorelease):

> When you autorelease, you're basically saying: "I don't need this any longer, but anyone else is free to pick it up (before the auto release pool is drained)". When you explicitly relase an object you're saying: "I don't need this any longer and unless anyone else has already said otherwise (acquired), it should be deallocated immediately."
>
> Consequently, autorelease is not
>   normally the wrong thing to. It is
>   required when you want to pass objects
>   back to the sender of a message
>   without requiring the sender to take
>   care of releasing the object.

However, I am still wondering what the second paragraph means. Autorelease is not normally the wrong thing to do... I thought it's really memory intensive, so it should naturally be the wrong thing to do. But as for the last sentence, I'm afraid I don't get it.

When do I really need to use autorelease and what would be a good example / rule of thumb that beginners can easily remember?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Autorelease is not normally the wrong
>   thing to do... I thought it's really
>   memory intensive, so it should
>   naturally be the wrong thing to do.

It's not "memory intensive" at all. If you allocate and autorelease a very large number of objects, such as in a loop, or a smaller number of large objects, you could run into problems. But autorelease just delays the release of objects that you're creating anyway, and which may or may not even be deallocated when the release does happen (the autoreleased objects may also be retained by other objects).

If you can release an object immediately, do that. If you need to autorelease, then do that and don't worry about the memory. If you're creating lots of objects in each iteration of a loop, you might want to consider either using your own autorelease pool or creating said objects with alloc/init so that you can release them immediately.

> But as for the last sentence, I'm afraid I don't get it.

If a method had to release every object that it created before returning, there'd be no way to return an object without requiring the caller to release the returned object. Autorelease allows a method to create an object and release it, but to defer that release until the caller has had a chance to use and possibly retain the returned object.

Comment: Thanks. But now I am entirely confused about the memory usage of autorelease as other people have told me the exact opposite: ONLY USE IT IF YOU REALLY REALLY HAVE TO... perhaps its best to talk about hard figures. An iPhone has how much memory? 256MB? How much of that is usually used for the iOS? How much is there for my App? How much does, for example, a simple string need in terms of memory? 256 bytes? How many strings would I need to create to run into serious memory problems so that it crashes my app? ... Sorry, but I'm thoroughly confused about all of this.

Comment: @n.evermind you should be fine using `autorelease` unless you can *prove* that its 1) causing a *measurable* slowdown in your app or 2) causing memory to build up unnecessarily.  You'll never be able to prove 1), and if 2) is a problem, you're always welcome to make your own autorelease pools.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the people you've given you this "only if you really have to" advice why they say that. Sounds more like superstition than good advice to me. Looking at TheElements in Instruments, I see 1017 live strings consuming about 28K of data. If you keep to that average, you'd have to create 37,000+ autoreleased strings to consume just one megabyte, and they'd all be released as soon as the autorelease pool is drained, which happens when control returns to the run loop (or when you drain your own pool).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation... actually, I won't ask the people who have said this as they are authors and probably not interested in what I have to say: From Appress Beginning iPhone 3 Development: "These objects can have a detrimental effect on your application’s memory footprint. It is OK to use autorelease, but try to use it only when you really need to, not just to save typing a line or two of code." I'd rather stick with your explanation as I like it better.

Comment: @n.evermind Mark & LaMarche are fine authors and smart guys who've helped a lot of people. But you have to consider that their goal is to maximize success for a group of beginners who, by definition, don't yet understand what they're doing, who are liable to do some crazy things, and who appreciate blanket rules like "always do this" or "avoid doing that." A few dozen autoreleased strings aren't going to hurt you; a few dozen autoreleased images could easily cause a memory warning.

Answer (score 1):

Like when you have a class, that has some random method called this:

```
- (NSString *)roflString { return [NSString stringWithString:@"ROFL!!!"]; }
```

You return an autoreleased object because it would be a pain to release the objects you get back from every method you call, it would make some things much more complicated to code.

So, whenever you have a method that returns an object in a class, make sure when it is retained that you autorelease it before you return it, so that the object that is calling the method doesn't need to bother releasing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that methods that are prefixed with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, `alloc`, `newObject`, or `mutableCopy`) return a retained object (you need to release it when you are done with it) whereas other methods return autoreleased objects (you don't need to release those but you need to retain them if you want to keep them). This is a convention by Apple and you should follow it when implementing your own classes.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if you use methods like NSString stringWithFormat NSArray arrayWithObjects, you're already getting and using autoreleased objects. Just follow the system behavior, and don't complicate things until Instruments or other performance data tells you otherwise.